# Gson to Plain Old Java Object(POJO)

Tags: java, json, pojo

I have read through the GSon user guide and looked at some questions on here but I am really struggling to understand why I am getting error whilst trying to make a java object with GSon

```
public class TestJSON extends ActionBarActivity {
    private Location start;
    private String length;
    private String url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test_json);

        // dummyprovider is provided by google to let me set a location.
        start = new Location("dummyprovider");
        start.setLatitude(51.5033630);
        start.setLongitude(-0.1276250);

        // Recieve an android warning if you run a retrieval task (such as JSON)
        // in the main thread).
        try {
            System.out.println("printing Json");

            Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {

                         toJava(readJsonFromUrl(urlBuilder()));
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
            thread.start();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.test_json, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    // I think in future I will call this function a ton of times and send it
    // some locations as waypoints for it to try and get closer to the
    // distances.
    private String urlBuilder() {
        String newUrl = url + start.getLatitude() + "," + start.getLongitude()
                + "&destination=51.5042178,23";

        return newUrl;
    }

    // Builds the string for JSON.
    private String readAll(Reader rd) throws IOException {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int cp;
        while ((cp = rd.read()) != -1) {
            sb.append((char) cp);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    // Take an input url and reads from it using the url above. We then put it
    // into a JSON object.
    private JSONObject readJsonFromUrl(String url) throws IOException,
            JSONException {
        InputStream is = new URL(url).openStream();
        try {
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,
                    Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
            String jsonText = readAll(rd);
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonText);

            return json;
        } finally {
            is.close();
        }
     }

    private void toJava(JSONObject obj) throws Exception {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        MapsRoute m = gson.fromJson(readJsonFromUrl(urlBuilder()).toString(),
                MapsRoute.class);
        System.out.println(m);

    }

    }
```

**MapsRoute.java**

```
public class MapsRoute {

        @SerializedName("routes")
        public List<String> routes;

        @SerializedName("copyrights")
        public String copyrights;

        @SerializedName("legs")
        public List<String> legs;

        @SerializedName("steps")
        public List<String> steps;

    }
```

This is the stack trace

```
  09-24 19:22:47.367: W/System.err(1720): com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 27
09-24 19:22:47.367: W/System.err(1720):     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:176)
09-24 19:22:47.367: W/System.err(1720):     at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:803)
09-24 19:22:47.367: W/System.err(1720):     at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:768)
09-24 19:22:47.367: W/System.err(1720):     at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:717)
09-24 19:22:47.367: W/System.err(1720):     at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:689)
09-24 19:22:47.367: W/System.err(1720):     at boyle.matt.runrouter.TestJSON.toJava(TestJSON.java:119)
09-24 19:22:47.367: W/System.err(1720):     at boyle.matt.runrouter.TestJSON.access$2(TestJSON.java:117)
09-24 19:22:47.371: W/System.err(1720):     at boyle.matt.runrouter.TestJSON$1.run(TestJSON.java:47)
09-24 19:22:47.371: W/System.err(1720):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
09-24 19:22:47.371: W/System.err(1720): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 27
09-24 19:22:47.371: W/System.err(1720):     at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.nextString(JsonReader.java:821)
09-24 19:22:47.371: W/System.err(1720):     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$13.read(TypeAdapters.java:358)
09-24 19:22:47.371: W/System.err(1720):     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$13.read(TypeAdapters.java:346)
09-24 19:22:47.371: W/System.err(1720):     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:40)
09-24 19:22:47.371: W/System.err(1720):     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:81)
09-24 19:22:47.371: W/System.err(1720):     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:60)
09-24 19:22:47.371: W/System.err(1720):     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:93)
09-24 19:22:47.371: W/System.err(1720):     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:172)
09-24 19:22:47.371: W/System.err(1720):     ... 8 more
```

I'm certain I am misunderstanding something simple and would really appreciate guidance.

this is the googlemaps url it is trying to parse, I am receiving it successfully as I can sys out it in my readfromurl method.

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=51.5033630,-0.1276250&destination=51.5042178,23

EDIT: This is the output when calling readsFromUrl(urlBuilder());

> 09-24 19:57:03.879: I/System.out(4068):
>   {"status":"OK","routes":[{"waypoint_order":
>   [],"summary":"A2","bounds":{"southwest":{"lng":-0.1262498,"lat":50.91870669999999},
>   "northeast":{"lng":23.0020594,"lat":52.4304362}},"legs":[{"duration":{"value":63803,"text":"17
>   hours 43 mins"},"distance":{"value":1825694,"text":"1,826
>   km"},"end_location":{"lng":23.0020594,"lat":51.50389209999999},"start_address":"70
>   Whitehall, London
>
> SW1A 2AS, UK","end_address":"Orzechów-Kolonia 2, 21-109
>   Orzechów-Kolonia,
>   Poland","start_location":{"lng":-0.1262498,"lat":51.5034032},"via_waypoint":[],"steps":[{"html_instructions":"Head
>   north</b> on Palace of Whitehall/Whitehall/A3212</b> toward
>   Horse Guards Ave</b>","duration":{"value":17,"text":"1
>   min"},"distance":{"value":157,"text":"0.2
>   km"},"end_location":{"lng":-0.1265332,"lat":51.50479920000001},"polyline":{"points":"ggjyH`tW]@cADYD[DUBWFy@PWD"},"travel_mode":"DRIVING","start_location":{"lng":-0.1262498,"lat":51.5034032}},{"html_instructions":"Turn
>   <b>right<\/b> onto <b>Horse Guards
>   Ave<\/b>","duration":{"value":53,"text":"1
>   min"},"distance":{"value":242,"text":"0.2
>   km"},"end_location":{"lng":-0.1231268,"lat":51.50464890000001},"polyline":{"points":"_pjyHxuWC]Ei@IgAAQAOAMAK?OAK?M?M?K?I?I@I?M@S`@wEPeBBY"},"start_location":{"lng":-0.1265332,"lat":51.50479920000001},"maneuver":"turn-right","travel_mode":"DRIVING"},{"html_instructions":"Turn
>   right</b> onto Victoria
>   Embankment/A3211</b>","duration":{"value":49,"text":"1
>   min"},"distance":{"value":389,"text":"0.4
>   km"},"end_location":{"lng":-0.1239744,"lat":51.5011942},"polyline":{"points":"aojyHp`WxH~Ab@H`En@~@F@?b@Bl@@"},"start_location":{"lng":-0.1231268,"lat":51.50464890000001},"maneuver":"turn-right","travel_mode":"DRIVING"},{"html_instructions":"Turn
>   left</b> onto Westminster Bridge Rd/A302</b>Leaving toll zone</div>Entering toll
>   zone</div>","duration":{"value":62,"text":"1
>   min"},"distance":{"value":507,"text":"0.5
>   km"},"end_location":{"lng":-0.1170572,"lat":51.50053550000001},"polyline":{"points":"myiyHxeW@ABABCB?DADCBABCBC@CBEBI?K@E@G@GBw@@}@@qA@q@DkFFkF?KFuAFgAEYC[Ai@?]@g@@iA?_@?O@U@Q@KBMBGBGP[FM"},"start_location":{"lng":-0.1239744,"lat":51.5011942},"maneuver":"turn-left","travel_mode":"DRIVING"},{"html_instructions":"Slight
>   left</b> to stay on Westminster Bridge Rd/A302</b>Leaving toll
>   zone</div>","duration":{"value":4,"text":"1
>   min"},"distance":{"value":26,"text":"26
>   m"},"end_location":{"lng":-0.1167459,"lat":51.5004276},"polyline":{"points":"kuiyHrzUFIBEBG@G@G@G?M"},"start_location":{"lng":-0.1170572,"lat":51.50053550000001},"maneuver":"turn-slight-left","travel_mode":"DRIVING"},{"html_instructions":"Turn
>   left</b> to stay on Westminster Bridge
>   Rd/A302</b>","duration":{"value":4,"text":"1
>   min"},"distance":{"value":23,"text":"23
>   m"},"end_location":{"lng":-0.1165272,"lat":51.5005834},"polyline":{"points":"utiyHtxUIQIMIK"},"start_location":{"lng":-0.1167459,"lat":51.5004276},"maneuver":"turn-left","travel_mode":"DRIVING"},{"html_instructions":"Slight
>   right</b> to stay on Westminster Bridge
>   Rd/A302</b>","duration":{"value":10,"text":"1
>   min"},"distance":{"value":52,"text":"52
>   m"},"end_location":{"lng":-0.1158714,"lat":51.5007879},"polyline":{"points":"suiyHhwUEa@GUGQQc@AE?G?G"},"start_location":{"lng":-0.1165272,"lat":51.5005834},"maneuver":"turn-slight-right","travel_mode":"DRIVING"},{"html_instructions":"Turn
>   right</b> to stay on Westminster Bridge Rd/A302</b>Continue to follow Westminster Bridge
>   Rd</div>Entering toll
>   zone</div>","duration":{"value":93,"text":"2
>   mins"},"distance":{"value":848,"text":"0.8
>   km"},"end_location":{"lng":-0.1051152,"lat":51.49874029999999},"polyline":{"points":"}viyHdsU@EBG@E@CBEBCFGNQBMFMLYZm@b@o@d@o@FUDKd@oAXe@Vs@~@iCN[DKFKDGBGJYb@_B\mBRiAHa@BO@I?G@E?G@UBe@@]CMAOIyAAo@?K?G?EGyAAe@EoAIwCKyCEoAAa@GiBIc@CQCW"},"start_location":{"lng":-0.1158714,"lat":51.5007879},"maneuver":"turn-right","travel_mode":"DR

Comment: Without looking into anything, what does `Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT` mean to you?

Comment: Debug and show what `json` you return from `readJsonFromUrl()`. It seems not a valid JSon object. Or at least not valid for your parser.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis nothing which is why I am asking for help :) googling is suggests it's because my string data structure was wrong but the other examples seem to use my setup.

Comment: I think you should stop everything you're doing and review [the json structure](http://json.org/). You can't expect a JSON object to be mapped to a Java `String`.

Comment: @Narmer added the sys out from debugging it.

Answer (score 0):

Hey the mapping of Java object with json is not proper.

example: routes has bounds,legs,copyrights,steps and not the way it has been mapped in the above code.

Comment: Please could you give a brief outline of the correct way to do it?

Comment: Define Route class,Bound class, Step class,Leg class. Route class has object of Bound class,Step class,CopyRight of String type,object of Leg class.Now you use this as outline.

Comment: ok so MapsRoute should have a public List<Route> route and then route should have List<Strings> for each of the other sections?

Comment: Suggestion :try to use the same names as in the json.It will be less confusion and better understanding.Its easy to map.

Comment: Is my approach correct though? route contains a bounds,copyright and legs object. A legs object contains steps object etc?

Comment: it seems your approach is ok.